# How to check Network Share response time using Python Script

Tags: python

Trying to write a script to check "Network share response time using Python.

```
file_name= f"\\\fileserver_name\\share_name$\\TestFile-{time.time()}.txt"

try:
    with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write('hello')  
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
            time.sleep(1)
            os.remove(file_name)
            print("done")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I am able to access the share but trying to implement timeout error if the share is not responded within timeout interval.

Looking for better ways to check network share response time using Python.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13686060/4603318

Comment: Thanks Amos Baker. I will try